# What are "User Defined Runtime Attributes" in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I can't seem to find any documentation on this feature at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For "custom objects", i.e. the ones for which you specify a different class than the one which is given initially, you can specify these "User Defined Runtime Attributes." This makes KVC attributes accessible from IB, when there is no IB Plugin for this class.